# Access denied while started browsermob proxy server

Tags: ruby, selenium, proxy, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use browsermob proxy in my Selenium tests. Hence I wrote following code:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'browsermob/proxy'

server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new ".//browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-8//"
server.start
```

But when I run above script, it results into `Access is denied. (5) (ChildProcess::LaunchError)` error:

```
c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.3.6/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:87:in `create_process': Access is denied. (5) (ChildProcess::LaunchError)
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.3.6/lib/childprocess/windows/process_builder.rb:34:in `start'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.3.6/lib/childprocess/windows/process.rb:63:in `launch_process'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/childprocess-0.3.6/lib/childprocess/abstract_process.rb:67:in `start'
        from c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/browsermob-proxy-0.1.3/lib/browsermob/proxy/server.rb:27:in `start'
        from test.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

Please help me to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the same issue and it was hard to figure out from the documentation [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/browsermob-proxy/0.1.7/frames/index) to understand that path to browsermob-proxy server should also include executable.

In your case the code should be the next:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'browsermob/proxy'

server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new ".//browsermob-proxy-2.0-beta-8//bin//browsermob-proxy.bat"
server.start
```

Hope it helps